# Finding the probability of normality via Anderson-Darling, Shapiro-Wilk , and Kolomogrov-Smirov

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution, normality-assumption, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, anderson-darling-test

I have quite a few distributions that were generated by some system, and I am trying to find the probability of accordance to normality for these distributions. So, the probability of accordance to normality could be found as:

## P(p>0.05) =  ( #p(AD test)>0.05 )/ total_no_of_distributions.

where p(AD test) refers to the AD test p-value resulted from fitting from fitting one distribution to normal, ( #p(AD test)>0.05 ) is the sum of all p's greater than 0.05, and P(p>0.05) is the probability of accordance to nomrmality.

My issue is that I intend to randomly try several methods, e.g., AD test, KS test, SW test, or LF test, to test the normality of the distributions that I have. A colleague has told me that this method might not be accepted because it is based on several methods and not one, which is quite orthodox. My idea is to propose a method that makes use of all the available normality testing methods, since it is difficult decide which one is more powerful.

I appreciate any comment and feedback to this issue.

Regards,
Rau

Comment: I think the idea of "probability of accordance to normality" has flaws. No distribution is perfectly normal, so, what exactly does this probability mean?

Comment: Well @PeterFlom everything is possible! Let me put two example, generated randomly generated via a normal distribution, and another from a uniform distribution (I am using matlab):
#p 
sample_size = 500; for i=1:100; [h p(i)]= kstest(randn(500,1)); end; P=sum(p>0.05)

P = 95

Comment: Now, let us try the uniform distribution:
 sample_size = 500; for i=1:100; [h p(i)]= kstest(rand(500,1)); end; P=sum(p>0.05)

P = 0

Comment: So, the probability of accordance of samples pooled from a uniform distribution is 0, while for samples randomly pooled from a normal distribution, the probability of accordance is 95%,....

Comment: No, the probability of a distribution being perfectly normal is 0. It's a question of how far from normality it is. p-values don't do what you seem to think they do.

Comment: the probability of a distribution being perfectly normal is 0???@PeterFlom, are you suggesting to use P(p<0.05), that will give 0 for perfectly normal distributions. To measure how far from normality it is, we can use the mean of AD test p-value (standard deviation, or the confidence interval), for these above examples: mean(P(rand_uniform)) =  3.0766e-110 (stdev=1.6809e-110), and mean(P(rand_normal))=  0.5089 (stdev =   0.5089), ..................... No?

Comment: No. The p value does not measure how far from normal a curve is. It measures how likely it is to get a AD score as extreme as the one you got in a sample the size of the one you have IF the population from which the sample was randomly drawn were perfectly normal.

Comment: What measures how far from normal a curve is? Or, there  isn't such a thing? If so, the AD test p-value could be a good alternative, although it measures how likely it is to get an AD score.........

Comment: You can look at the area between the curves. You could, I think, bootstrap that. If you want to continue the discussion, perhaps we should move to chat

Comment: @PeterFlom Why not KL divergence? Wouldn't information theory be the go-to for distance between distribution? (We even have a correct/reference distribution in the assumed normal, arguably, so the asymmetry of KL seems not to be an issue.)

Answer (score -1):

I think that if you use several normality tests, then any rejection should be counted as a rejection. The tests which you mentioned all have null hypotheses of normal distribution.

Comment: Anyone following this advice will experience a false positive rate far greater than the intended one.  It's an extreme example of the multiple comparisons problem.